# Цикл внутри each

Tags: jquery

Есть список элементов с одним классом, нужно из массива присвоить им id равные значениям массива

```
                  $('.lqwest').each(function(){
                    var cft = iq_id[i];
                    $('.lqwest').attr('id','q'+cft));
                  });
тут он выдает всем один и тот же id равный первому значению массива
```

как сделать чтобы выдавал все поочередно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.lqwest').each(function(index){
    var cft = iq_id[index];
    $('.lqwest').attr('id','q'+cft));
});
```

Comment: В вашем случае получатся одинаковые id все равно. Автор вопроса просто затер function(i) когда редактировал вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Вы в каждом проходе присваиваете одно и то же значение всем элементам набора, а не каждому по отдельности. Надо присваивать каждому по отдельности:

```
$('.lqwest').each(function(i){
    var cft = iq_id[i];
    $('.lqwest').eq(i).attr('id','q'+cft));
});
```

А лучше воспользоваться таким способом, он более правильный:

```
$('.lqwest').each(function(index,element){
        $(element).attr('id','q'+iq_id[index]));
});
```